# Wildcard certificate supporting both www and non-www domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I have a GeoTrust wildcard certificate installed on my website www.example.com.
It is working fine with https://www.example.com but it is not supporting https://example.com. It shows a security warning that your connection is not secure and in advances pane its showing that this certificate is supporting only three listed domains.
Could you please help me into this?

Comment: Give us the actual domain so we can take a look.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Your certificate was issued to

- CN=*.example.com

and does not contain X509v3 Subject Alternative Name for the following domains:

- *.example.com
- example.com

You need to get a new certificate.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name

You can dump your certificates with the following command, to verify:

```
openssl x509 -text -in <certfile> -noout
```

Comment: Not true. *.example.com includes example.com and www.example.com. For instance the *.pfsense.org cert is fine on https://pfsense.org/ and https://www.pfsense.org/

Comment: You are wrong, pfsense org comes with the two X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:*.pfsense.org, DNS:pfsense.org

Comment: Yeah, the SAN is generally standard and automatic. I guess OP's CA might not have added the SAN automatically.